# Importar pagina de ionic en una pagina no-ionic

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ionic

Estaba trabajando en una app de ionic, y en esta realicé una página que es para el header, la cual se muestra en todas las páginas de ionic. Empecé a trabajar en una página pura de html, css y js la cual no estaba conectada a ionic porque se me complicó mucho hacerla allí. Ahora, que quiero unir ambos, quiero importar el header que realicé en ionic en mi página de html, pero no me deja, y no estoy seguro siquiera de que lo esté haciendo bien

---

En mi header de ionic, `header.page.html` tiene

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-buttons slot="start">
            <ion-menu-button menu="main-menu">
                <img src="../../assets/Logo_sin_letra.png" slot="start" class="Logo" />
            </ion-menu-button>
        </ion-buttons>
    </ion-toolbar>
    <ion-toolbar color="danger" *ngIf="!appIsOnline">
        <ion-input readonly id="appIsOnline" value="{{ appIsOnline }}">Sin conexión a internet :'(</ion-input>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

y en el `header.page.ts` tengo

```
import { Network } from '@capacitor/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.page.scss'],
})
export class HeaderPage implements OnInit {
    constructor(){}
  async ngOnInit() {
    const status = await Network.getStatus();
    this.appIsOnline = status.connected;

    Network.addListener('networkStatusChange', (status) => {
      this.appIsOnline = status.connected;
    });
  }
}
```

En mi `pagina.html`, la que cree desde 0

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <link href="style/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script type="module" src="../pagina/js/price.js"></script>
  <link href="https://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0/css/ionic.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://code.ionicframework.com/1.0.0/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<ion-nav [root]="headerPage"></ion-nav>
<!-- El resto del html -->
</body>
```

Y, según yo, intento importarlo desde el `price.js`

```
import { HeaderPage } from '../../CompraVenta/src/app/header/header.page';
headerPage = new HeaderPage(); //Para poderlo usar en el html
```

Ionic corre sobre angular, no se sii ayude, pero para